Store last 4 characters of encrypted field
We have a SSN field on Account object which is currently encrypted. I want to create another field on Account and store last 4 characters of SSN. I tried below formula but looks RIGHT is not supported on encrypted field. What option do I have to resolve this?
Formula I tried - RIGHT(SSN_C,4)
Error: You referenced an unsupported field type called "Text (Encrypted)" using the following field: RIGHT

You are correct that the RIGHT function cannot be used on encrypted fields in Salesforce. Encrypted fields have several limitations, including not being available for use in formulas due to their encrypted nature.
To work around this limitation you can use apex trigger. You could write an Apex trigger that fires on record creation or update. This trigger would extract the last four characters from the SSN field and then store them in a new custom field.
Example:
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, before update) {
        for (Account acc : Trigger.new) {
        // Assuming 'SSN__c' is your encrypted field and 'Last4SSN__c' is your new custom field
                String fullSSN = (String)acc.SSN__c;
                if (fullSSN != null && fullSSN.length() >= 4) {
                        acc.Last4SSN__c = fullSSN.substring(fullSSN.length() - 4);
                }
        }
}

You must ensure that the user context under which the code is executed has the "View Encrypted Data" permission to access the decrypted value of the SSN field.

You should ensure the value is only calculated and updated when the trigger is on create or it is on update and the source field has actually changed. Also, why not use String.right and are you sure the permission is required?

Thank you, I will try this option.

We do not want to go with Apex trigger. One of the reason we need last 4 characters of SSN was to display on screen using flow. We decided to access the full SSN field in flow and then use string functions to pull last 4. As data is only encrypted at rest, this solution worked and met our needs. Thank you everyone for your suggestions.
